# Shorhand for a = (a == val1) ? null : val1;

Tags: javascript, function, expression, shorthand

Any ideas about the expression to make it even shorter:

```
a = (a == val1) ? null : val1;
```

The logic of this expression (if important) actually is:

make it expanded (among others) if it is clicked and not expanded YET. And if it is expanded ALREADY and just clicked, then close it (then set to null). 
With another words, decline setting `a` as `val1` only if it is set already to `val1` and replace it with null (change from opened to closed).

Comment: Also, the code doesn't work. Did you mean `:` instead of `||`?

Comment: @CBroe The reason: looks too long for me... Just curious if I'm missing something so that SO community could help... Refactoring... Optimization... That's the only reason...

Comment: @HemanGandhi You're right. Thank you very much. The error was updated.

Comment: Shorter: `a = a == val1 ? null : val1;`. Or if `val1` is truthy, `a = a ? null : val1;`.

Comment: Or: `a = a^val1 ? val1 : null;` (for integers)

Comment: Now, if you're just looking for an 'on' / 'off' flag, simply start with `a = 0` and do `a ^= 1`. Or start with `a = false` and do `a = !a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do `a = !a && val1` if you dont mind switching between false and val1.

This is based on the behaviour of `&&` operator in javascript: if first operand is true `&&` operator assigns the second operand, else it returns first operand.

Please note: This does make your code more difficult to read. If you want this to make sense to another developer you would have to add a comment explaining what this line does.

Comment: *"and operator in javascript: if both conditions are true && operator assigns the second parameter, else it returns false"* - Not quite. If the first operand is truthy `&&` returns the second operand regardless of its value, else it returns the first.

Comment: You are right, I understood it wrong, will update. Thanks!